# MySQL INNER join with RIGHT join and multiple conditional WHERE clause with FULL TEXT

Tags: php, mysql, join, full-text-search, rdbms

I have three tables:

```
Meta
Posters
Tags
```

Posters has a many-to-one relationship on id to Meta. Tags has a many-to-one relationship on poster_id to Posters.

```
Meta <-- many-to-one Posters <-- many-to-one Tags
```

so a Meta item can have many posters, and a poster can have many tags.

I am trying to create a SINGLE query that can accept conditional filters including specific `Tag` types.

```
function get_filter_posters($filters, $start) {
      $query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.id AS poster_id, Posters.filename, Meta.imp_title
                FROM Meta INNER JOIN Posters ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
                RIGHT JOIN Tags ON Posters.id = Tags.poster_id
                WHERE Meta.year >= :lower
                AND Meta.year <= :upper ";

      foreach ($filters["genre"] as $key => $value) {
        if($value){ $query .= " AND Meta.genre = '".$key."' "; }
      }

      foreach ($filters["style"] as $key => $value) {
        if($value){ $query .= " AND Tags.tag = '".$key."' "; }
      }

      $query .= "ORDER BY Meta.year DESC
                 LIMIT :start,:limit";

      $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
      $statement->bindParam(':limit', $this->limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->bindParam(':lower', $filters["year_range"][0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->bindParam(':upper', $filters["year_range"][1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->execute();
      return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
```

this works only when a SINGLE style element is true. If more than one style element is found to be true, and therefore an additional where clause is added:

```
      foreach ($filters["style"] as $key => $value) {
        if($value){ $query .= " AND Tags.tag = '".$key."' "; }
      }
```

then the query always returns an empty set when there is in fact a single poster with multiple tags.

if a query is written with just a single style element set to true, then the query returns proper posters. More than one, ALWAYS returns empty, which is not the case.

also this will be extended with a TEXT search as well. This one dosnt work at all as expected.

```
$query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.id AS poster_id, Posters.filename, Meta.imp_title,
              MATCH(".$search_type.") AGAINST($term) AS Relevance
              FROM Meta INNER JOIN Posters ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
              RIGHT JOIN Tags ON Posters.id = Tags.poster_id
              WHERE MATCH(".$search_type.")
              AGAINST($term IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

      foreach ($filters["genre"] as $key => $value) {
        if($value){ $query .= " AND Meta.genre = '".$key."' "; }
      }

      foreach ($filters["style"] as $key => $value) {
        if($value){ $query .= " AND Tags.tag = '".$key."' "; }
      }

      $query .= "AND Meta.year >= ".$filters["year_range"][0]."
                 AND Meta.year <= ".$filters["year_range"][1]."
                 ORDER BY Relevance + Meta.year DESC
                 LIMIT :start,:limit";

      $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
      $statement->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->bindParam(':limit', $this->limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $statement->execute();
      return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

disregard the fact that i didnt `bindParam` the filter years - it will be done

Maybe i am approaching this in an incorrect way? If so, any advice would greatly help

THANK YOU!

Comment: Move                 WHERE Meta.year >= :lower
                AND Meta.year <= :upper "; to the join condition of tags and meta.  You're saying you want to return all tags but only those in meta that match.  (your right join) so when no match is found meta.year will be null and therefore evaluate to false.... you have two options first move it to the join criteria, second wrap it in ()'s and add OR (meta.year is null).  (change '`WHERE`' to '`ON`')

Answer (score 2):

The right join is being negated by the where clause meta.year statement.  Thus if a tag exists, without posters or meta data, it is being EXCLUDED (the right join in essence is being treated as a INNER JOIN).  To correct, you would need to make the where clause limits on meta part of the join either at the posters level or the tag right join...

perhaps

```
  $query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.id AS poster_id, Posters.filename, Meta.imp_title
            FROM Meta 
            INNER JOIN Posters ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
            RIGHT JOIN Tags ON Posters.id = Tags.poster_id
             ON Meta.year >= :lower
            AND Meta.year <= :upper ";
```

or

```
  $query = "SELECT Meta.id, Meta.year, Posters.id AS poster_id, Posters.filename, Meta.imp_title
            FROM Meta INNER JOIN Posters 
              ON Meta.id = Posters.movie_id
             AND Meta.year >= :lower
             AND Meta.year <= :upper
            RIGHT JOIN Tags ON Posters.id = Tags.poster_id";
```

Comment: the second suggestion with a RIGHT join returns NULL values, with a LEFT join it returns everything